# Undefined index: dontprint

Tags: php, excel, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to use php-excel-reader(http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/php-excel-reader/) extension to upload excel file into database. I was trying to implement the example function provided in the extension page. But i keep on getting the error "Undefined index: dontprint".I am not able to understand what is causing the error. please help.This is my controler code.

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    Yii::import('ext.phpexcelreader.JPhpExcelReader');
    $data=new JPhpExcelReader(Yii::app()->getBasePath().'/import/example.xls');
    echo $data->dump(true,true);
}
```

This is the code involving dontprint in extension code.

```
for($col=1;$col<=$this->colcount($sheet);$col++) {
    // Account for Rowspans/Colspans
    $rowspan = $this->rowspan($row,$col,$sheet);
    $colspan = $this->colspan($row,$col,$sheet);
    for($i=0;$i<$rowspan;$i++) {
        for($j=0;$j<$colspan;$j++) {
            if ($i>0 || $j>0) {
                $this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row+$i][$col+$j]['dontprint']=1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!$this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row][$col]['dontprint']) {
        $style = $this->style($row,$col,$sheet);
        if ($this->colhidden($col,$sheet)) {
            $style .= "display:none;";
        }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't PHPExcel, it's PHP-excel-reader.... there's a big difference

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google shows an identical issue happening when iconv isn't installed and enabled, do you have that installed/enabled?

Comment: i just uncommented the following lines: 'iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1'

Comment: i got it solved with out using this extension, but by using YiiExcel. Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

IT's a notice.. Problem solved with adding on Controller

```
 error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_WARNING);
```

But this is not a safe solution.